# Upconversion/ Grouping using Map Reduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, location, bigdata

I have 2 documents

1. List of offerings and associated zip codes
2. US Postal code data.

The first document is of the form:

```
offer, location(currently only zips)
1, 84121
1, 84101
1, 58103
1, 58102
2, 84121
2, 84101
...
...
```

This list has over 4 billion rows.

The second is a lit of Zip code data from the USPS with relevant columns:

```
Zip, City, State
84121, Salt Lake, UT
84101, Salt Lake, UT
....
....
```

On a small scale I can run a series of set differences to up convert the offers to their respective states, and cities incase all the zips for the state or city are contained.
EG:
by grouping the zips for an offer into a set I get
    1, set([84121, 84101, 58103, 58102 ....])

Then grouping the second list by state:
    UT, set([84121, 84101, .....])

So now I can run a set difference between all 50 states iteratively 
So it UT zips - zips for offer 1 is an empty set.
I can subtract UT zips from Offer 1 and add UT and so on.
So if offer 1 has all zips for UT and AZ and only a few from Washington DC
I want to end up with

```
offer, location
1, UT
1, AZ
1, 20011
....
....
```

Then I run the same process iteratively for all cities to up convert the remaining zip codes for every offer.

Needless to say this process is extremely inefficient and does not scale well.
I am not sure what a better solution would be. 
I have looked into this post [here](http://codingwiththomas.blogspot.com/2011/06/set-intersection-and-difference-with.html) and though this method works well for intersecting 2 sets I don't see it fit for my case.
Thanks

Comment: The manner in which the question is posted is a little confusing, and probably that is why we see no responses. Right now you have clubbed your question and the possible solutions together for example "So now I can run a set difference between all 50 states iteratively..." I would suggest that you separate out your question and then have a possible solution section and then mention the cons of your solution. This way people like me can understand the question and help. Thanks